# is there a simple way to getting text associated of a label exists in a radio button using webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a html like below:
Assume Male is already selected, how can i know Male is selected???

```
<input id="radio1" type="radio" value="1" name="sex>
<label class="radio" for="radio1">Female</label>
<input id="radio2" type="radio" value="2" name="sex>
<label class="radio" for="radio2">Male</label>
```

I know we can get the selected radio button with below code. But is these any simple of retrieving this?

```
List<WebElement> radioBrns=driver.findElements(By.name("sex"));
for(WebElement radio:radioBrns)
{
    if(radio.isSelected())
    {
        String forID=radio.getAttribute("id");
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='"+forID+"']")).getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably look for all the input tags with id starting with radio and when ever a radio gets selected some of the attribute changes its value or either a new attribute gets added in that element or parent element. like [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio)

you can see that Male radio button as

> checked

attribute
your xpath then would be something like this : `.//input[@checked]`

Edit
Search for Siblings in XPath in google and you should find a way to do that.
Let me know if this helps

Comment: as mentioned in my above code, by the first statement of if condition i will  know the input tag and then i am looking for label. But is there a way to combine these two and get a simple way?

Comment: yes you can do that. do u have a public url.. where u can show me the same dom structure, then i can suggest xpath to do that

Comment: Though this is same any many sites aswell. You can take facebook.com as an example where it will show male and female  radio button.